# How to determine which process is using a file?

Tags: python, windows, filesystems

I am trying to merge two PDFs using PyPDF2.  Sometimes I run into the following error:
`[WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:`
How can I determine which process is using the file?

Thank you

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows.

Comment: Please update your question with the source code you have written for this program.

Comment: Note that it could be due to the PyPDF2 process itself. The error message for a sharing violation is very misleading (and should have been fixed 20 years ago). A file's share mode has absolutely nothing to do with a process. It's related only to previous opens that requested any kind of data access (read/execute, write/append, or delete).

Answer (score 0):

You might have already tried this, but try to find the handle or the DLL ; a dialogue box will open and allow you to search for the missing file. If you want to open a file in Python, search up a file handling cheat-sheet. It doesn't require any importing of modules, just the Open() function. Glad to help if i did